# Use a generating function to find the number of multisets of balls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> From a set of nine colored balls, including three red, four blue, and two
>   green, five balls are selected. However, it is required that at least one red ball is included and that the number of blue balls included is even. Use a generating
>   function to find how many ways this can be done.

The given g.f expression is $(R + R^2 + R^3)(1 + B^2 + B^4)(1 + G + G^2)$ which is actually $x(1 + x + x^2)^2(1 + x^2 + x^4)$.

I thought the g.f. should be $(R + R^2 + R^3)(1 + B^2 + B^4)(1 + G + G^2 + G^3)$. For example, we can choose $2$ red, $3$ green and $0$ blue balls because $0$ is even.

Can someone, please, explain why the third factor in the product shouldn't have the term $G^3?$ Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From a set of nine colored balls, including three red, four blue, and two green, five balls are selected.

The number of green balls in the bag is two and hence the maximum number of green balls we can select is two.

Comment: This has to be the dumbest mistake I have ever made. Thanks.